# Webbrowser control issue in citrix server?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, citrix

I am using a web browser control in my Win Form which is installed in a citrix server when i try to open the application in my local it is working fine (even in IE) without any errors.When I try to open the same application after deploying in server, inside the web browser control I am getting some Java script errors while loading the form.

JavaScript errors are: (Internet Explorer script error)

1. Invalid character in URL
2. ASP.NET Ajax client side framework failed
3. "Sys" is undefined.

Is this error is because of the site which is opened in a control or any configuration is missing or IE issue?? Please help

Thanks in advance.